# elasticsearch: match query can get result, but more like query can not

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question about an elasticsearch query:

I have two docs, the content field used standard analyzer, the values are :

1. "content": "But Buffett's stake in Wells Fargo, and **johnson hot** stakes in a number of other major banks"
2. "content": "Taco Bell's chief information **johnson hot** Fancher told Nation's Restaurant News that mobile is their prime focus at the moment"

I can get these two docs when I used match query:

```
localhost:9200/content/en-us/_search?pretty=true -d '
{    
"query" : {
    "match" : {
        "content" : "johnson hot"
    }
  } 
}'
```

But I can't get them using more like query:

```
localhost:9200/content/en-us/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "more_like_this_field": {
            "content": {
                "like_text": "johnson hot",
                "min_term_freq": 1,
                "max_query_terms": 12
             }
        }
    }
}'
```

result:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
}
```

Does anybody know why?
Is the more like query  similar with the "like" in SQL?

Thanks
Johnson

Comment: please post the
 mapping of your document..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More like this field query will give you the similar docs by matching the content of the specified fields.

You have to set **min_doc_freq** to 1. The default value for this is 5, so the it ignores the terms in **like_text if** they don't appear in more than 5 docs. As you have only two docs both the terms **jhonson** and **hot** will be ignored. Below query will should work

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/content/en-us/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 200,
  "query": {
    "more_like_this_field": {
      "content": {
        "like_text": "johnson hot",
        "min_term_freq": 1,
        "max_query_terms": 12,
        "min_doc_freq": 1
      }
    }
  }
}'
```